# Reset UNUserNotificationCenter to notDetermined on macOS

Tags: macos, unusernotificationcenter

I want to test my UNUserNotificationCenter authorization workflow for my MacOS app. I can't seem to find a way to reset the authorization status to `notDetermined` again. tccutil doesn't seem to contain any options for this, and one approach I found from [this link](https://alexandersandberg.com/articles/how-to-reset-notification-permissions-on-macos/) doesn't seem to actually work. Any suggestions?